# Change the value of an attribute in an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a requirement such that for certain type of scope variables, I want to keep two decimal places in AngularJs. For this I've done the following:

`html`

```
<span floatval="{{someVariable}}">{{someVariable}}</span>
```

`js`

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]).directive('floatval', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        var newInt = parseFloat(attrs.floatval);
        var n = newInt.toFixed(2);
    }
});
```

I'm stuck here as I dont know how to now reflect this new value in the place of the original scope `{{somevariable}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the scope of your directive. This way two-way binding is setup.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]).directive('floatval', function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            floatval: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.floatval = parseFloat(scope.floatval).toFixed(2);
        }
    };
});
```

Then you need to change your HTML `<span floatval="someVariable">{{someVariable}}</span>`

See https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/directive

Link to an example plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/aRyp1v9tGH7z8X28fewP?p=preview

Comment: Does this work the same for version 1.2.x? Because I seem to be getting a syntax error using this.

Comment: You need to change your assignment from `{{value}}` to just `value` in your html view

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use built-in filters?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number